# Converting java to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, orbit

I'm developing a Kotlin application with the orbit package, but I'm with some issues to define actors `Unresolved reference: T`

```
class HelloActor():AbstractActor<T>,Hello
```

What should be the T param? In docs: `* @param <T> a class that represents the state of this actor.`

Comment: What happens if you try `HelloActor<T>()` in place of `HelloActor()`

Comment: `This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here`

Comment: @lai0n Are you using Intellij IDEA? You can implement your class in Java and then [convert to Kotlin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html)

Comment: @ledniov not work. Same first question error

Comment: `class HelloActor extends AbstractActor[AnyRef]` In orbit Scala examples, is write like this

Comment: For whatever reason I didn't found any sort of `AbstractActor` with a type parameter. Are you using [this one](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/AbstractActor.html)?

Comment: @glee8e It's not akka. It is https://github.com/orbit/orbit/blob/master/actors/core/src/main/java/cloud/orbit/actors/runtime/AbstractActor.java

Comment: What you probably need is class `HelloActor<T>():AbstractActor<T>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand that actor framework, but base on detail you have given in comments, I think you should replace T with either `Any`.

Your HelloActor should looks like this:

```
class HelloActor(): AbstractActor<Any>,Hello
```

In kotlin, `Any` is mapped to `java.lang.Object`, or `AnyRef` in scala, and they have the same functionality and purpose. `Any` may be used wherever `Object` or `AnyRef` is used. See more kotlin to Java class mapping [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

EDIT: Actually kotlin is more similiar to Java, so you should follow the Java tutorial instead of scala ones.

Comment: Kotlin `Any` is not equivalent to Java `Object`. It is just mapped so in the bytecode. Moreover, Kotlin `Any` does not have the same functionality and purpose of Java `Object` and Scala `AnyRef`. Kotlin `Any` is more like Scala `AnyVal`. `Any` is a supertype of all types, including primitive types like `Int` and `Double`.

Comment: @Naetmul Yes I know that, but in practice they can be considered the same. And Kotlin doesn't emphasis the difference between primitive type and its wrapper type. Unlike Java, it uses the same name and you has no mean to explicitly use the wrapper type (or reverse). So it's hard to say it's `AnyVal` or `AnyRef`, or even `Any`, because in kotlin there is no place for `AnyVal`.